# Netty http count requests

Tags: netty

I am writing simple hhtp server using Netty.

How can i count all requests (connections) and active connections using Netty?
I am using example  https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http and trying to count my requests. Should i use my own  'counter' to do that or any ready functions to count?

Also, i need to store some data (for example how many times each request were accessed), what is the best way to store that and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement your own counter, into the handler which handles the http request or into one specific handler added on pipeline for this purpose. I prefer the second option to better separate role of pipeline. Moreover, you can just stop counting by removing the specific handler of pipeline.

Comment: like adding in my initChanel method:
pipeline.addLast(MyOwnHandler())