# Netty: several handlers, byte counter

Tags: java, netty

1. I am new to Netty and trying to count received and sent bytes for each channel. I found that i should use ChannelTrafficShapingHandler for that but i have no idea how to reach my goal. As i undersand, i should write my own handler which will exetds from ChannelTrafficShapingHandler with adding some methods? It would be great to provide real code examples.

   ```
   @Override
   public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
   ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
   if (sslCtx != null) {
       p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
   }
   p.addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder());
   // Uncomment the following line if you don't want to handle HttpChunks.
   //p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));
   p.addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder());
   // Remove the following line if you don't want automatic content compression.
   //p.addLast(new HttpContentCompressor());
   p.addLast(new HttpSnoopServerHandler());

   p.addLast(new ChannelTrafficShapingHandler(0, 0));
   ```

   }

like adding class to handlers, but how can i use that?

2. I wrote post ([Netty http count requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473579/netty-http-count-requests)) and was advised to write my own handler to count my requests, opened connections etc. However, i can't understand how to manage different url's with different handlers. For example, i have url /info - that's okey and I want to handle it in Handler #1. Then, i have url /statistic and i want to count there my values and print them. This url should be managed by Handler #2. How could i do that?
3. I have a lot of data which i should output on page(like several tables), what should i use for that? I think that string is not suitable for huge output

Thank you for your patience and answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a `HttpObjectAggregator` handler on pipeline. It will handle all http chuncks for you and put on pipeline a `FullHttpRequest`.

Then, implement a handler extending `SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest>` and add it at the end of the pipeline. On the `FullHttpRequest` catched into this handler you have methods to get headers, requested URI, content, etc. You can store content data size as you want into a map or other, by requested path, etc. Implement all you need.

For the response, if you use http/html, you use text (so strings). Instantiante an instance of `DefaultFullHttpResponse`, and put your html text as content for this response. Next, you have just to push it on pipeline by calling `ctx.writeAndFlush()` (the `HttpResponseEncoder` will convert the message into a valid http response for you).

Moreover, you can optionnaly add a `HttpContentCompressor` on pipeline to activate compression when possible.

Comment: Thank you so much fo this response. I have one more detail to ask: could I create header and footer as html pages and then just "append" them to my response. The reason is that i want to write as less html in string as possible

Comment: I'm not sure to understand but Yes, in the handler, you can compute your dynamic response in a string, and add enclosing html tag or header before sending it